# Why does a UNION bring back a null row?

Tags: sql, t-sql, union

I have two select statements.

```
SELECT ...

UNION

SELECT ...
```

If I run the first SELECT, the data comes back fine.

If I run the second SELECT, the data comes back fine.

If I run both at the same time using a UNION, the first row is always a NULL.

I don't get it. Anyone know why this could be causing an issue?

Comment: can you post the full query and then some sample data and desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a NULL row in your data.  What is hapening is that the `union` is doing a sort, which is bringing the NULL up to the first row.

If you want to eliminate the NULL value, use a `where` clause.

If you want your query to be more efficient by not eliminating duplicates, using `union all`.

Comment: but if I run the 2 selects separately, there are no null rows in either of the results...

Comment: If the `union` is creating NULL rows, then there is a bug in the SQL engine.  That seems unlikely to me.  Is it possible you have a `where` clause on the second query, that you think is being applied to the entire result set, but is really being applied only to the first subquery?